# Format datatable row based on header information

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using the datatables plugin and would like to be able to format a row based on it's content and the content of the header.

The way I do it now, the formatting is based on column index. If the user rearranges columns or I add or move columns in the future, the formatting will be incorrect.

Is there a way to reference both the table header name and the cell content when using this function? Below is my current code.

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {

               if (aData[7] != "" ){
                    $('td', nRow).css('color', 'red');
                    }   
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use property based approach:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {

        if (aData.myPropertyName != "" ){
            $('td', nRow).css('color', 'red');
        }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but being relatively new to programming, I'm not sure I understand. It looks like aData is only passing cell values, no the header values. I would like to format a cell if it's empty and the header name was "Hold", for example.